# Is there anyway to make this code more efficient? I am running it on a sparse matrix (m) that is around 190k x 30k. Perhaps a way to get rid of loops?

Tags: python, loops, matrix, sparse-matrix, bioinformatics

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
import sys
import heapq
from .kmeanspp import kmeanspp
from .utils import log
from fbpca import pca
import math as math
import statistics
import random
import operator as op
import time

lil=m.tolil()
gene_avg=[]
cell_rndm=random.sample(range(lil.shape[0]), round(lil.shape[0]*rndm_cell_pcnt))
print('calculating gene averages')
for gene in range(lil.shape[1]):
    print('calculating mean')
    gene_avg.append(lil[:,gene].todense().mean())
print('setting chosen cells to cell type random. changing gene expression')
for cell in cell_rndm:
    nonzero=set(lil[cell,:].nonzero()[1])
    rndm_nonzero=random.sample(nonzero,round(len(nonzero)*gene_prcnt))
    zero =list(set(list(range(lil.shape[1])))-nonzero)
    rndm_zero=random.sample(zero,round(len(zero)*gene_prcnt))
    print('setting celltype to random')
    labels[cell] = 'random'
    print('reraranging some gene expresion')
    lil[cell,rndm_nonzero]=0.0
    lil[cell,rndm_zero] = list(itemgetter(*rndm_zero)(gene_avg))
```

In the first for loop, I am giving all 30k genes their mean expression. In the second I am going through all 190k cells and setting some nonzero genes to zero and zero ones to the average. This process takes a very long time.

Comment: Do you really need the sparse representation here?  `m` isn't too big for a regular dense numpy array.

Comment: include your imports with the code; I can guess what they are, but just to be sure.

Comment: There's a lot of problems with the how you're doing this, sure - but this is a terrible way to build a noise-dominated negative control dataset, or to add noisy observations to an existing dataset. You should ask that question, not how to optimize this bad idea.

Comment: @hpaulj The sparse matrix is the raw form of the data, and the algorithms I'm working with takes sparse. I also put up the imports I am using, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for gene in range(lil.shape[1]):
    print('calculating mean')
    gene_avg.append(lil[:,gene].todense().mean())
```

should be replaceable with

```
arr = lil.A  # dense array
gene_avg = arr.mean(axis=1)
```

With numpy random, you should be able to take all 'random-samples' at once.  I haven't studied your code enough to give you the details.

While `lil` assignment is the best for sparse matrices, assigning values to dense arrays is better - if they fit in memory.

Trying to understand the action:

For one `cell` (random list, no repeats), hence `lil[cell,:]` is a row of the `lil`.

Get the nonzero indices, as a `set`.  `set(lil.rows[cell])` may do the same thing:

```
nonzero=set(lil[cell,:].nonzero()[1])
```

then get a random sample of those:
rndm_nonzero=random.sample(nonzero,round(len(nonzero)*gene_prcnt))

And a random sample of the zeros, using `set` difference.  Use of `set` feels like it might be slower than needed, but I haven't worked out an alternative.

```
zero =list(set(list(range(lil.shape[1])))-nonzero)
rndm_zero=random.sample(zero,round(len(zero)*gene_prcnt))
```

Prints are great for debugging, but they do slow down the run.

```
print('setting celltype to random')
labels[cell] = 'random'
print('reraranging some gene expresion')
```

And finally set some elements of that row to 0

```
lil[cell,rndm_nonzero]=0.0
```

If `gene_avg` is an array, then you can use `gene_avg[rndm_zero]` instead of this `itemgetter`.  I don't think `itemgetter` is any faster than `[gene_avg[i] for i in rndm_zero]`.

```
lil[cell,rndm_zero] = list(itemgetter(*rndm_zero)(gene_avg))
```

While it would be nice to work with all sampled rows at once

```
arr[cell_rndm]
```

it would take a lot of work to get the details right.  So for a start I'd focus on streamlining the row by row operation.

Comment: With gene_avg = arr.mean(axis=1) shouldn't axis = 0?